# PHP DOMDocument loadHTML returns two HTML childNodes

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am running PHP in Visual Studio and was looking to step over the various nodes in an HTML string. I loaded the string into DOMDocument using loadHTML and extracted the firstChild from the document, checked and it was a HTML node, but the node did not have any children.

I then modified the code to step over all childNodes of the document and to my surprise this returned two HTML nodes, the second one having the expected child nodes. Is this what I should be expecting and can anyone explain why?

Code and output attached.

```
enter code here
<?php
$html = '<html><head></head><body>';
$html .= '<h1>Content 1</h1><h2>Content 1.1</h2><h3>Content 1.1.1</h3>';
$html .= '</body></html>';

define ('NEWLINE',"\r\n" );

function recurceHTML ($node, $spaces)
{
    $nextIndent = $spaces . '  ';
    print ($spaces . $node->nodeName . NEWLINE);
    foreach($node->childNodes as $childNode)
    {
        recurceHTML ($childNode, $nextIndent);
    }
}


$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$spaces = '  ';

foreach ($dom->childNodes as $child)
{
    recurceHTML ($child, $spaces);
}
$wait = readline();
?>
```

Output from above is:

```
  html
  html
    head
    body
      h1
        #text
      h2
        #text
      h3
        #text
```

Comment: As an addendum to the question. I even tried removing the <html> tags from the string, but that had no effect. The output was identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slight update to your code to show the content it is using more clearly, you can see where the data is coming from...

```
function recurceHTML ($node, $spaces)
{
    $nextIndent = $spaces . '  ';
    print ($spaces . $node->nodeName."->".$node->nodeType . NEWLINE);

    if ( $node->nodeType == 1 ) {
        foreach($node->childNodes as $childNode)
        {
            recurceHTML ($childNode, $nextIndent);
        }
    }
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$spaces = '  ';

echo $dom->saveHTML().PHP_EOL;

foreach ($dom->childNodes as $child)
{
    recurceHTML ($child, $spaces);
}
```

The first `echo` shows you the actual document it is working with...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head></head><body><h1>Content 1</h1><h2>Content 1.1</h2><h3>Content 1.1.1</h3></body></html>
```

As you can see - this also has the document type as part of the content.

Then you have the output of the main function...

```
  html->10
  html->1
    head->1
    body->1
      h1->1
        #text->3
      h2->1
        #text->3
      h3->1
        #text->3
```

The output after the tagName shows the [node type](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.constants.php), the first one is 10 which is the [DOMDocumentType](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumenttype.php) node ( the `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3...`), then the second one is type 1 which is [`XML_ELEMENT_NODE`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) which is your `<html>` tag.

As your using `loadHTML` - this will always attempt to create a valid HTML document - this includes adding the document type as well as the `<html>` tags etc which would be needed in a normal HTML page.

Comment: Thank you for the explination and insight. What threw me when I first started iterating over the document was that I was expecting a single <html> child node, getting two was a puzzle. And you are correct I was not looking at the Node Type.

Comment: DOMDocument is great for really detailed taking apart of XML (and HTML), but it is too fine grained for some.  There is a lot of junk created if you just want to parse content, but you need it when you are creating more dynamic content.  SimpleXML is great for strict XML, but fails miserably if you need anything more than the basics.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, and again for the help. The reason for parsing the HTML is to add anchoring points as id attributes to header elements for Table of Content generation. Oh - I also wanted to say thanks for the "echo $dom->saveHTML().PHP_EOL" trick, that has already proven itself a real help.